# Ways to shorten relation chain between objects

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-key-relationship

for example i have code like this

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def review_count(self):
        return Review.objects.filter(order__product_id=self.id, published=True).count

class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)

class Review(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and very often i need to display number of reviews for every Product. 
I found to ways to do it -

1. property **review_count** - it's looks fine, but on set of Product objects it's very slow.
2. annotate with .extra method - it's faster, but require additional SQL(i think, i cant simply use annotate because of filtering on review object by published=True).

I think, that if i have additional field 'product' with fk to Product on Review model, i will can get set of products easily and faster, but in this case field 'product' will be dependent from field 'order', that not good for normalization, i think.

P.S.: One order may have few Reviews - it's ok. And order related to Review for check that one order dont have too much review - moderation issue.

Help me, please, how i can improve this scheme, to get review count on products faster and easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you say you can't use the `annotate()` method because you need to filter. That is not only supported, but [explicitly described](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations) in the documentation.

```
Product.objects.filter(order__review__is_published=True).annotate(Count('order__review'))
```

Comment: I need all Products in set, not only with reviews and it's possible with:
Product.objects.annotate(Count('order__review'), Q(order__review__is_published=True))
Thanks!